# How to remove skype ID and all its traceable things after using skype?

Tags: windows-7, skype

Usually skype displays in a list all signed in ID's in a list at the log in screen. I have a personal ID in skype to communicate with few persons only but after using it on a shared computer my ID also is being displayed in that list, but I don't want it. So after using skype how can I remove my ID and all its traceable things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 7 go to `%appdata%\Skype\` and delete the folder with the name equal to the ID you want to clear from the list.

Note: This will delete all information Skype holds for this login ID, not only it's name from the login MRU list.